"D:/work/python/projects" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Terminal problem in Pycharm
When I open a terminal in PyCharm then this error appears:
D:/work/python/projects : The term 'D:/work/python/projects' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check t
he spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ D:/work/python/projects pycharm/Web1/.venv/Scripts/activate.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:/work/python/projects:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException".

when I open "pycharm/Web1/.venv/Scripts/activate.ps1".

You need to activate the virtual environment, you call pycharm/Web1/.venv/Scripts/activate in your terminal/cmd
without any file extensions, then it will take a second and activate the virtual environment.
